# Row styling depends of case in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, html-email

I am trying to make HTML report in SQL Server.
I have to make row background color different when one of my cell contains sth.

It is possible to add class to tr tag in case of ... or just defined style attrib?

## edit

```
DECLARE @tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX) ;
DECLARE @dzisiaj as date
SET @dzisiaj = CAST(CONVERT(varchar(10), GetDate(),126) as varchar)
DECLARE @tytul as varchar(100)
SET @tytul = 'Raport z dnia ' + cast (@dzisiaj as varchar)    

SET @tableHTML =
N'<style type="text/css">
    h1 {font-size: 24px; font-family: Verdana;}
    td,th {min-width:100px;max-width:200px;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;text-align:center;font-family:Verdana;padding:4px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color: black;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal; line-break: word-wrap}
    th, .first {font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;background-color:#354458;color:#ffffff;} 
    td {font-size: 10px;background-color:#DCDDCD;color:#000000; }
</style></br></br>' +
N'<H1>Raport z dnia ' + cast (@dzisiaj as varchar) + '</H1>' +
N'<table border="1">' +
N'<tr><th>Lp</th><th>Filia</th><th>Nazwa</th>' +
CAST (( 
  SELECT 
    td = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o_filia asc), '',
    td = [o_filia], '',
    td = [o_opis], '',

  FROM [dbo].[oddzialy]
  ORDER BY o_filia asc
FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) +  '</table>' ;

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients='tomipnh@gmail.com',
@subject = @tytul,
@body = @tableHTML,
@body_format = 'HTML' ;
```

I want to use different background-color in case o_filia equals "A"
It is there simple trick or I have to use case statement of whole row generate?

Comment: Show your current query and how you make HTML report

Comment: Why not just use a general purpose language like c# or python to create the report from the database results?

Comment: @Nick Bailey I can't :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sp\_send\_dbmail - formatting row in table as red for an alert](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161771/sp-send-dbmail-formatting-row-in-table-as-red-for-an-alert)